# Can't get RewriteEngine URL to work

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently my links are like:

http://config.website.nl/?show=home
and I want to it to look like this: 
http://config.website.nl/Home

Now I have been looking at a lot of RewriteEngine scripts, but they are all way more advanced and I don't seem to get it to work...

This is my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/ index.php?show=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?show=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?show=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked. Although I used to set links like http://config.website.nl/?show=home but I noticed for this script I have to use http://config.website.nl/index.php?show=home with the "index.php" included

Comment: Updated rules to make it work for `config.website.nl/index.php?show=home` also.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?show=$1
```

#### index.php

```
<?php
$show = (isset($_REQUEST['show'])) ? strtolower($_REQUEST['show']) : null;

print_r($_REQUEST);

switch ($show) { 
    case "about":
        echo 'About us... <a href="/home">Go back home</a>';
    break;

    case "home":
    default:
        echo 'Welcome to the home page... <a href="/about">Visit the about us page</a>';    
    break;
}

?>
```

Be careful: lots of people think that .htaccess will 'automagically' change all of the links you write as `index.php?show=about` into `/about`. This is not the case. You'll have to configure your PHP to echo your links in the correct format manually (see above).

p.s. Depending on server, you may, or may not, need the RewriteBase line. This is why you see it commented out in several examples.

Comment: Note that if your URI is `/Home`, `$_GET['show']` will have **Home**, not **home**. You will have to have code (like @Dave shows with strtolower() ) to lowercase the string before doing a comparison. Count on users typing in both Home and home.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have an extra trailing slash in your last rewrite rule. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) index.php?show=$1
```